# Syntax error when using caret for exponentiation

Tags: fortran

When I do:

```
   REAL FUNCTION  f(x)          
      REAL, INTENT(IN) :: x
      f = exp(-x)
    END FUNCTION  f
```

it works but if I do:

```
   REAL FUNCTION  f(x)          
      REAL, INTENT(IN) :: x
      f = exp(-x^2)
    END FUNCTION  f
```

I get an error:

```
  Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

but I need the `x^2` function not the `x`. What to do?

Comment: u can try:  f= exp((-x)^2)

Comment: @Novice: yeah, OP could try that and get the same error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `x ** 2` to exponentiate. Or `x*x` in this case.

Comment: +1, Simple & correct. If I am not mistaken "^" is not even an operator in fortran.