# Unclassified statement at (1) in a mathematical expression

Tags: plot, fortran, subroutine, polynomial-math

My first Fortran lesson is to plot the probability density function of the radial Sturmian functions. In case you are interested, the radial Sturmian functions are used to graph the momentum space eigenfunctions for the hydrogen atom.

In order to produce these radial functions, one needs to first produce some polynomials called the Gegenbauer polynomials, denoted

C<sub>b</sub><sup>a</sup>(x),

where a and b should be stacked atop each other. One needs these polynomials because the Sturmians (let's call them R_n,l) are defined like so,

R_n,l(p) = N  <sup>p<sup>l</sup></sup>⁄<sub>(p<sup>2</sup> + k<sup>2</sup>)<sup>l+2</sup></sub>   C<sub>n - l - 1</sub><sup>l + 1</sup>(<sup>p<sup>2</sup> - k<sup>2</sup></sup>⁄<sub>p<sup>2</sup> + k<sup>2</sup></sub>),

where N is a normalisation constant, p is the momentum, n is the principle quantum number, l is the angular momentum and k is a constant. The normalisation constant is there so that when I come to square this function, it will produce a probability distribution for the momentum of the electron in a hydrogen atom.

Gegenbauer polynomials are generated using the following recurrence relation:

C<sub>n</sub><sup>l</sup>(x) =  <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>[2(l + n - 1) x C<sub>n - 1</sub><sup>l</sup>(x) - (2l + n - 2)C<sub>n - 2</sub><sup>l</sup>(x)],

with C<sub>0</sub><sup>l</sup>(x) = 1 and C<sub>1</sub><sup>l</sup>(x) = 2lx, as you may have noticed, l is fixed but n is not. At the start of my program, I will specify both l and n and work out the Gegenbauer polynomial I need for the radial function I wish to plot.

The problems I am having with my code at the moment are all in my subroutine for working out the value of the Gegenbauer polynomial C<sub>n-l-1</sub><sup>l+1</sup>(<sup>p<sup>2</sup> - k<sup>2</sup></sup>⁄<sub>p<sup>2</sup> + k<sup>2</sup></sub>) for incremental values of p between 0 and 3. I keep getting the error

```
Unclassified statement at (1)
```

but I cannot see what the issue is.

```
program Radial_Plot

    implicit none

    real, parameter :: pi = 4*atan(1.0)
    integer, parameter :: top = 1000, l = 50, n = 100
    real, dimension(1:top) :: x, y
    real increment
    real :: a=0.0, b = 2.5, k = 0.3
    integer :: i
    real, dimension(1:top) :: C

    increment = (b-a)/(real(top)-1)

    x(1) = 0.0
    do i = 2, top
        x(i) = x(i-1) + increment
    end do

    Call Gegenbauer(top, n, l, k, C)

    y = x*C
    ! y is the function that I shall be plotting between values a and b.


end program Radial_Plot


Subroutine Gegenbauer(top1, n1, l1, k1, CSub)

    ! This subroutine is my attempt to calculate the Gegenbauer polynomials evaluated at a certain number of values between c and d.

    implicit none

    integer :: top1, i, j, n1, l1
    real ::  k1, increment1, c, d
    real, dimension(1:top1) :: x1
    real, dimension(1:n1 - l1, 1:top1) :: C1
    real, dimension(1:n1 - l1) :: CSub


    c = 0.0
    d = 3.0
    k1 = 0.3
    n1 = 50
    l1 = 25
    top1 = 1000


    increment1 = (d - c)/(real(top1) - 1)

    x1(1) = 0.0
    do i = 2, top1
        x1(i) = x1(i-1) + increment1
    end do


    do j = 1, top1

     C1(1,j) = 1
     C1(2,j) = 2(l1 + 1)(x1(i)^2 - k1^2)/(x1(i)^2 + k1^2)
     ! All the errors occurring here are all due to, and I quote, 'Unclassifiable statement at (1)', I can't see what the heck I have done wrong.
        do i = 3, n1 - l1
                C1(i,j) = 2(((l1 + 1)/n1) + 1)(x1(i)^2 - k1^2)/(x1(i)^2 + k1^2)C1(i,j-1) - ((2(l1+1)/n1) + 1)C1(i,j-2)
        end do

    CSub(j) = Cn(n1 - l1,j)^2

    end do
    return
end Subroutine Gegenbauer
```

Comment: Please tell us the complete error message.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17669736/3157076.

Comment: The complete error message is important.

Answer (score 1):

As francesalus correctly pointed out, the problem is because you use `^` instead of `**` for exponentiation. Additionally, you do not put `*` between the terms you are multiplying.

```
 C1(1,j) = 1
 C1(2,j) = 2*(l1 + 1)*(x1(i)**2 - k1**2)/(x1(i)**2 + k1**2)

 do i = 3, n1 - l1
            C1(i,j) = 2 * (((l1 + 1)/n1) + 1) * (x1(i)**2 - k1**2) / &
                      (x1(i)**2 +  k1**2)*C1(i,j-1) - ((2(l1+1)/n1) + 1) * &
                      C1(i,j-2)
 end do

CSub(j) = Cn(n1 - l1,j)**2
```

Since you are beginning I have some advice. Learn to put all subroutines and functions to modules (unless they are internal). There is no reason for the `return` statement at the and of the subroutine, similarly as a `stop` statement isn't necessary at the and of the program.